# Load more datas when scrolling on a GridView Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, gridview, scroll, lazy-loading

I am making an application where I can run through items in a GridView on a profile page, like on Instagram when we scroll our posts.

I want to load more items (15 per 15) when I scroll on my GridView.
I want an infinite loading.

So I added a ScrollListener to my GridView.

If I put an "initialScrollOffset" to "5.0" in attribute to my ScrollListener, it will load the 15 first items and make one loading, so it's add 15 items (work only 1 time), but if I let the default value, it loads no items.

I would like to have an infinite loading.

**My GridView code :**

```dart
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:dresskip/model/item_model.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ItemSection extends StatefulWidget {
  const ItemSection({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _ItemSectionState createState() => _ItemSectionState();
}

class _ItemSectionState extends State<ItemSection> {
  List<Item> items = [];
  bool isLoading = false;
  int pageCount = 1;
  ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController(initialScrollOffset: 5.0);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    ///LOADING FIRST  DATA
    addItemsToList(1);

    _scrollController.addListener(_scrollListener);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Row(),
        GridView.count(
          controller: _scrollController,
          crossAxisCount: 3,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          //physics: const ScrollPhysics() /*AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()*/,
          mainAxisSpacing: 0,
          children: items.map((value) {
            return Image.network(value.picture);
          }).toList(),
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  //// ADDING THE SCROLL LISTINER
  _scrollListener() {
    //inspect(_scrollController.offset);
    if (_scrollController.offset >=
            _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent &&
        !_scrollController.position.outOfRange) {
      setState(() {
        print("comes to bottom $isLoading");
        isLoading = true;

        if (isLoading) {
          print("RUNNING LOAD MORE");

          pageCount = pageCount + 1;

          addItemsToList(pageCount);
        }
      });
    }
  }

  addItemsToList(int page) {
    //if (page < 5) {}
    Item myItem = Item(
        name: "test",
        brand: "test",
        color: ["0xFF39BDC8", "0xFFdb8abc", ""],
        picture:
            "https://images.pexels.com/photos/9676177/pexels-photo-9676177.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260",
        //"https://scontent.fcdg2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.6435-9/171944671_3950113148381954_7059062044076097927_n.jpg?_nc_cat=110&ccb=1-5&_nc_sid=09cbfe&_nc_ohc=gxbPXmRQmN8AX9V5Bx5&_nc_ht=scontent.fcdg2-1.fna&oh=ac2a57c8c1d1b0b01fcf131ac42c4023&oe=6190A9BF",
        solo: false,
        clean: true,
        type: "test");
    for (int i = (pageCount * 15) - 15; i < pageCount * 15; i++) {
      items.add(myItem);
      isLoading = false;
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

**Item model class**

```dart
class Item {
  String name;
  String brand;
  List<String> color;
  String picture;
  bool solo;
  bool clean;
  String type;

  Item({
    required this.name,
    required this.brand,
    required this.color,
    required this.picture,
    required this.solo,
    required this.clean,
    required this.type,
  });
}
```

**The first part (profile section) code**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '/assets/constants.dart' as constants;
import '../../assets/dresskip_icon_icons.dart' as DresskipIcons;

class ProfileSection extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<String> description;
  final VoidCallback onClicked;

  const ProfileSection({
    Key? key,
    required this.description,
    required this.onClicked,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 10),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment
                  .spaceBetween, //pour que chaque colonnes dans la ligne ait leurs propres tailles
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment
                  .start, //pour tout coller en haut du container
              children: <Widget>[
                const Icon(Icons.local_laundry_service),
                Stack(children: [
                  buildImage(),
                  Positioned(
                      bottom: 0,
                      right: 4,
                      child:
                          buildEditIcon(Color(constants.COLOR_BLUE_DRESSKIP)))
                ]),
                const Icon(Icons.settings),
              ],
            ),
            // Partie description
            Container(
                child: Text(description[0]),
                margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(50, 5, 50, 5)),
            // Partie Instagram
            Container(
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      child: const Icon(DresskipIcons.DresskipIcon.instagram),
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 20, 0),
                    ),
                    Expanded(child: Text(description[1]))
                  ],
                ),
                margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 5, 20, 5)),
            // Partie Facebook
            Container(
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      child: const Icon(Icons.facebook),
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 20, 0),
                    ),
                    Expanded(child: Text(description[2]))
                  ],
                ),
                margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 5, 20, 5)),
            // Partie Twitter
            Container(
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      child:
                          const Icon(DresskipIcons.DresskipIcon.twitter_square),
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 20, 0),
                    ),
                    Expanded(child: Text(description[3]))
                  ],
                ),
                margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 5, 20, 5)),
          ],
        ));
  }

  // Widget pour afficher l'image
  Widget buildImage() {
    // use if is an image on the web with the link : final image = NetworkImage(imagePath);

    return ClipOval(
        child: Material(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            child: Ink.image(
              image: const AssetImage("assets/undraw_female_avatar.png"),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              width: 128,
              height: 128,
              child: InkWell(onTap: onClicked),
            )));
  }

  // Widget pour l'ajout de l'icone à coté de l'image
  // Ici, il y a 2 fois buildCircle pour arrondir l'icone et ensuite mettre le trait blanc arrondi entre la photo et l'icône
  Widget buildEditIcon(Color color) => buildCircle(
      color: Colors.white,
      all: 1,
      child: buildCircle(
          color: color,
          all: 8,
          child: Icon(Icons.add_a_photo, color: Colors.white, size: 20)));

  // Widget permettant d'arrondir l'image
  Widget buildCircle({
    required Widget child,
    required double all,
    required Color color,
  }) =>
      ClipOval(
          child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(all), color: color, child: child));
}
```

**The parent page code**

```dart
import 'package:dresskip/model/user_model.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'itemSection_widget.dart';
import 'profileSection_widget.dart';
import '/assets/constants.dart' as constants;

import 'dart:convert';

class AccountPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const AccountPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
      children: [
        ProfileSection(
            description: getUserInformation().properties,
            onClicked: () async {}),
        const Divider(
          color: Color(constants.COLOR_BLUE_DRESSKIP),
          thickness: 2,
          indent: 50,
          endIndent: 50,
        ),
        ItemSection()
      ],
    )));
  }

  getUserInformation() {
    User myUser = User(username: "test", email: "test@test.test", properties: [
      "22 yo\nFlexeur/Epicurien/Philanthrope\nJ'adore la vie\nEFREI Paris",
      "instagram_test",
      "facebook_test",
      "twitter"
    ]);
    return myUser;
  }
}
```

There are 2 screenshots of my App.

The problem here, it's just loading 15 + 15 items (the first 30) and I can't load more data on scrolling.

[image: My App with my GridView : 1]

[image: My App With my GridView at the end of the GridView]

**EDIT**

I find a way to resolv this problem. The attribute "shrinkwrap" block the possibility to scroll more because my widget which contains the gridview is into a Column Widget.

So i removed it, but just the Gridview is scrolling, I would like to do like Instagram's profil, when you scroll on your pictures, all the page scroll and not only the GridView.

Do you have an idea ?

Comment: Your code-snippet is working fine, can you include top part of the widget where it is having profile details.

Comment: if you want to use a third-party package then this is the best package out there!
https://pub.dev/packages/infinite_scroll_pagination

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I'm doing it

Answer (score 1):

#### Endless / Infinite Scroll GridView

This example uses a `GridView.builder` & doesn't need a `ScrollController`.

When the end of the current dataset is reached, it will request more data and rebuild the `GridView`.

We can pad the end of the dataset with a special item.  When this special item is built by `GridView.builder`, it will:

1. show a loading indicator
2. request more data from datasource
3. rebuild the GridView when data arrives

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class InfiniteScrollPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Infinite Scroll'),
      ),
      body: EndlessGrid());
  }
}

class EndlessGrid extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _EndlessGridState createState() => _EndlessGridState();
}

class _EndlessGridState extends State<EndlessGrid> {
  NumberGenerator _numGen = NumberGenerator();
  List<int> _data = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _data = _numGen.nextPage();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.builder(
      itemCount: _data.length + 1, // pad data with an extra item at end
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisSpacing: 10, mainAxisSpacing: 10, crossAxisCount: 2),
      itemBuilder: (context, i) {
        if (i < _data.length) {
          return gridItem(i);
        }
        else { // extra item will request next page & rebuild widget
          getNextPage();
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
      },
    );
  }

  Widget gridItem(int i) {
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.lightBlue
      ),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
      child: Text('$i'),
    );
  }

  /// Request next page of data and call setState to rebuild GridView with
  /// new data.
  Future<void> getNextPage() async {
    var _nextPage = await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), _numGen.addPage);
    setState(() {
      _data = _nextPage;
    });

  }
}

/// Mock data to fill GridView
class NumberGenerator {
  static const PAGESIZE = 15;
  List<int> dataset = [];
  final int start;

  NumberGenerator({this.start = 0});

  List<int> addItem() {
    dataset.add(lastItem + 1);
    return dataset;
  }

  List<int> addPage() {
    dataset.addAll(nextPage());
    return dataset;
  }

  int get lastItem => dataset.isNotEmpty ? dataset.last : start;

  List<int> nextPage({int start, int size = PAGESIZE}) {
    start ??= lastItem;
    return List<int>.generate(size, (i) => start + i + 1);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I'm not aware of Instagram UI.

The problem is here with parent, while `SingleChildScrollView` is the parent and you want to scroll the full page and generate GridItem based on it, therefore set we don't need to `ScrollController` for `GridView` instead use it on `SingleChildScrollView`.

The code structure will be

- parent class generate data for GridView and will be `StatefulWidget`.
- while there are two scrollable widgets so that `GridView < physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),>`
- AccountPage: `SingleChildScrollView` will have that `_scrollController`
- `ItemSection` can be `StatelessWidget`

**Full Code snippet with dummyHeaderWidget**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AccountPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const AccountPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AccountPage> createState() => _AccountPageState();
}

class _AccountPageState extends State<AccountPage> {
  ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
  bool isLoading = true; // 

  int pageCount = 1;
  List items = [];
  //// ADDING THE SCROLL LISTINER
  void _scrollListener() {
    print(
        "current ${_scrollController.offset}  max: ${_scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent}");

    if (_scrollController.offset >=
            _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent &&
        !_scrollController.position.outOfRange) {
      setState(() {
        print("comes to bottom $isLoading");
        isLoading = true;

        if (isLoading) {
          print("RUNNING LOAD MORE");

          pageCount = pageCount + 1;
          addItemsToList(pageCount);
        }
      });
    }
  }

  addItemsToList(int page) {
    //if (page < 5) {}
    Item myItem = Item(
        name: "test",
        brand: "test",
        color: ["0xFF39BDC8", "0xFFdb8abc", ""],
        picture:
            "https://images.pexels.com/photos/9676177/pexels-photo-9676177.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260",
        //"https://scontent.fcdg2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.6435-9/171944671_3950113148381954_7059062044076097927_n.jpg?_nc_cat=110&ccb=1-5&_nc_sid=09cbfe&_nc_ohc=gxbPXmRQmN8AX9V5Bx5&_nc_ht=scontent.fcdg2-1.fna&oh=ac2a57c8c1d1b0b01fcf131ac42c4023&oe=6190A9BF",
        solo: false,
        clean: true,
        type: "test");
    for (int i = (pageCount * 15) - 15; i < pageCount * 15; i++) {
      items.add(myItem);
      isLoading = false;
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _scrollController.addListener(_scrollListener);
    addItemsToList(1);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        controller: _scrollController,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 300,
              color: Colors.green,
            ),
            const Divider(
              thickness: 2,
              indent: 50,
              endIndent: 50,
            ),
            ItemSection(
              items: items,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ItemSection extends StatelessWidget {
  final List items;
  const ItemSection({
    Key? key,
    required this.items,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.count(
      crossAxisCount: 3,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      mainAxisSpacing: 0,
      children: items.map((value) {
        return Image.network(value.picture);
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
}

class Item {
  String name;
  String brand;
  List<String> color;
  String picture;
  bool solo;
  bool clean;
  String type;

  Item({
    required this.name,
    required this.brand,
    required this.color,
    required this.picture,
    required this.solo,
    required this.clean,
    required this.type,
  });
}
```

Read the code, hope you will get concept and make changes on your project.